# xcode installation

Tags: macos, xcode4.4

I am new to Mac and Xcode. I downloaded xcode .dmg file from app store and copied to my mac.After installing, it did not create any /developer folder and i can not see it in installed app on app store.But I can launch Xcode from the virtual drive which is created by .dmg file.Please guide me for proper installation.I am using Mac osx lion and XCode4.4.1.

Comment: App Store install will have created XCode.app in /Applications there is no /Developer for Xcode 4.4 and also I don't think a .dmg

Comment: no. it is not there in /application also and i am not able to find Xcode.app in spotlight also.

Comment: App Store does not give you .dmg what exactly did you do to get the app?

Comment: I downloaded from my windows pc from Internet explorer using my Apple ID. This gave me a .dmg file. This i copied to my mac PC. 1st time it tried to install app. after that every time i use it to launch app. the path of Xcode.app is /Volumes/XCode

Comment: please put all details into the question as what yiou are saying now is not what you asked. You say ist time it tried to install - what did it do? and what is in /Applications - Why can't you just run AppStore from your Mac?

Comment: Did you try dragging `Xcode.app` from the `.dmg` to `/Applications` or `~/Applications`?

Answer (score 0):

press command+spacebar, type xcode and see if you can locate it

Comment: No. I am not able to locate it in spotlight

Comment: install it again. At the end of the installation you will get a small window. Drag xcode icon and put it in application icon.